# Why isn't this code allowing me to connect the vertices of the drawing?

Tags: java, graphics, trigonometry

I'm meant to draw a pentagon with lines going from the vertices to the centre. These 'arms' are being drawn correctly but when I try to connect the vertices it is being drawn incorrectly. To connect the lines I placed another draw function in the loop as below, which should take the end point coordinates of the first line drawn as the starting point, and the end point coordinates of the next 'arm' that is drawn in the iteration, as its end point. Am I missing something here? Am I wrong the use 'i+angle' in the second draw?

```
for (int i = 0; i < arms; i += angle) {
            double endPointX = armLength * Math.cos(i*angle-Math.PI/2);
            double endPointY = armLength * Math.sin(i*angle-Math.PI/2);
            double endPointX2 = armLength * Math.cos((i+angle)*angle-Math.PI/2);
            double endPointY2 = armLength * Math.sin((i+angle)*angle-Math.PI/2);
            g2d.drawLine(centreX, centreY,centreX+ (int) endPointX,centreY+ (int) endPointY);
            g2d.drawLine(centreX+ (int) endPointX,centreY+ (int) endPointY, (int) endPointX2,(int) endPointY2);
        }
```

Comment: The angle seems to be in degrees. Use `double angleRad = Math.toRadians(angleDeg)` to convert the angle to radians before using it in any trigonometric function like `sin` or `cos`

Comment: And it should probably be `(i+1)*angle` instad of `(i+angle)*angle`

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for this [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/shape/) in PolygonFactory

Abstractly, the way to generate a regular polygon with n points is to put these points on the unit circle. So:

- Calculate your angle step, which is 2 * pi / #vertices
- Calculate your radius
- Starting at angle 0 (or an offset if you want) use Math.sin(angle) and Math.cos(angle) to calculate the x and y coordinates of your vertices
- Store the vertex points somewhere / somehow. If you look at the [Polygon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html) class or the class I wrote, you can get some ideas on how to do this in a way that is friendly to converting to a java.awt.Polygon.